# JQuery file attachment: TypeError: $(...) is null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below code that helps in creating an custom option to attach a file. When i run the code i get this error TypeError: $(...) is null. I occurs in the 1st line of the code it self. I am trying to use this on a ticket form. Could some one let me know what is the error in my code. It does not work in Zendesk portal.

```
var frame=$('#upload_frame').html('<iframe></iframe>').find('iframe');
var fileform='<form method="POST" action="/fileuploads?format=js"> Attach log files <input type="file"></form>';
var frameinit=function() {
frame.contents().find('body').children().remove();
frame.contents().find('body').append(fileform);
frame.contents().find('input').change(function(){
frame.contents().find('form').submit();
});
    };
frameinit();
  $('#SelectFile').click(
 function() {
 frame.contents().find('input').click();
    //Callback to load the result from iframe
    frame.load(function() {
        //it is  just for jsfiddle
    var data=frame.contents().find('.pageHeader');
    $('body').append($('<div>').html(data));
        frameinit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you haven't included the jQuery library itself. You need to include it like that

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks the error does not show. However the file is not reflecting when i check the submitted form.